# Fourth root of unknown positive constant-4th order DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, roots

I am attempting to solve a fourth order homogeneous linear differential equation:
$${d^4y\over dx^4}-ay=0$$
The auxiliary equation is
$$m^4-a=>m^4=a$$
But I don't how to find the roots of $$\sqrt[4]{a}$$ where 'a' is an unknown positive constant. I would appreciate your help in this regard.

Comment: The roots are $\pm \sqrt[4]{a}$ and $\pm i \sqrt[4]{a}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Omnomnomnom has expressed the values obtained from the equation $m^{4} = a$ are $m \in \{\sqrt[4]{a}, - \sqrt[4]{a}, i \sqrt[4]{a}, -i \sqrt[4]{a} \}$. The application of these values to the differential equation is the following.
\begin{align}
y^{(4)}  - a y = 0
\end{align}
has solutions of the form $y = e^{\alpha x}$ and leads to the equation $\alpha^{4} = a$. From this the solutions is of the form
\begin{align}
y(x) &= A \, e^{\sqrt[4]{a} x} + B \, e^{-\sqrt[4]{a} x} + C \, e^{i\sqrt[4]{a} x} + D \, e^{-i\sqrt[4]{a} x} 
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
y(x) &= A \, \cosh(\sqrt[4]{a} x) + B \, \sinh(\sqrt[4]{a} x) + C \, \cos(\sqrt[4]{a} x) + D \, \sin(\sqrt[4]{a} x).
\end{align}